# OS X Global Shortcuts in C++

Tags: c++, macos, qt, keyboard-shortcuts

I am currently working on a QT application (in C++) that lives in the system tray, and requires a global shortcut. Currently it does not seem as though QT provides a way to register global shortuts with the OS. I've located Qxt (http://libqxt.org), however for various reasons this library will not suffice.

Therefore, I am looking for a way to register a global shortcut within OS X, so that even if my application does not have focus (remember it's in the system tray!) that I can still interact with its functionality.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's `RegisterEventHotKey` (Carbon). A thorough write up [can be found here](http://dbachrach.com/blog/2005/11/program-global-hotkeys-in-cocoa-easily/).

You could also install a `CGEventTap`. This is slightly more complex to write, but still quite short. [A demo can be found here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200503003001/http://osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter2/alterkeys/).

Comment: I stumbled across RegisterEventHotKey after I posted this. How would I call that from C++? I've only found references for objective-c.

Comment: @Louis I've linked an example - just stop after the definition of `MyHotKeyHandler` (It's all C up to that point).

Comment: @Louis you're welcome. just in case you're new to OS X development; don't get too attached to Carbon implementations (they are legacy APIs).

Comment: So i've read. Perhaps I need something more long term - any other suggestions I could consider?

Comment: I mentioned `CGEventTap` - would it not work for you? http://osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter2/alterkeys/

Comment: I'll look into it, I'm not really sure. I suspect that it would also function as a global hotkey? I took a look at Carbon, and it seems I don't even have the Carbon framework on my system (Snow Leopard)...

Comment: yes - you could use it to intercept user input. the example swaps a and z. Carbon.framework is on my system! (X.6.8)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6563/discussion-between-louis-and-justin)